# Cloudinary API uploads photo to cloud but doesn't return result from callback

Tags: image, api, meteor, callback, cloudinary

Im using meteor event and I want to upload an image to cloudinary. I have tried this code snippet below and it uploads a file to cloudinary but I don't get any result back from the callback.

```
"change input[type='file']": function(e) {
var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
console.log(file);
Cloudinary._upload_file(file, function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Upload Error: " + err);
    return;
  }
      console.log("Upload res: " + res);
    });
```

I've tried to mix the code up but it still doesn't return anything.. Any advice ? Am I doing the callback wrong?

Comment: which package/api did you use Cloudinary server? I have an web-app working just fine. Though mine was a bit different. I passed an extra object to locate the directory of the server.

Comment: I'm using this package from atmosphere: [link](https://atmospherejs.com/lepozepo/cloudinary)

Comment: Aren't you missing a parameter when calling the _upload_file function?
`_upload_file: (file, ops={}, callback)`

Comment: I tried that too, I don't know why this never worked and I never got a return from the api call. I ended up using amazon s3 which worked perfectly..